# Exception when reading from Contacts

Tags: android, exception, android-contacts

I am trying to write a routine that adds Contacts to my Android phone's AddressBook. I am getting the following exceptions:

```
D/dalvikvm(  784): GC freed 2736 objects / 171696 bytes in 71ms
E/IMemory (  784): binder=0x5b5248 transaction failed fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Unknown error: 2147483646)
E/IMemory (  784): cannot dup fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Bad file number)
E/IMemory (  784): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x5b5248), size=0, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
E/JavaBinder(  784): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder(  784): java.lang.RuntimeException: No memory in memObj
E/JavaBinder(  784): at android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
E/JavaBinder(  784): at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:518)
E/JavaBinder(  784): at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:27)
E/JavaBinder(  784): at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:493)
E/JavaBinder(  784): at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:496)
E/JavaBinder(  784): at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:96)
E/JavaBinder(  784): at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:287)
E/JavaBinder(  784): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Can anyone detail on what the above logs mean?

Comment: Please note that pid: 784 is the process id for Contact aggregation.

Comment: How were you able to determine the pid of Contact aggregation?

Comment: I traced the logs back to the origin in ddms.

Answer (score 0):

Wow that's a weird one.

I don't think this will help but check it out: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/33fd9e9f7bd43d26?fwc=1

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

I just fix this problem in my application. The problem is with closing the cursors, if you post your code I can correct it.

Marius

Comment: Hi Marius.. Thanks for you reply. I had figured that out later and already made the change.